# Is "headed back inside again" correct?

Tags: grammar

The drunk man came out onto the porch with a bottle of beer. He drank it and headed back inside. A few moments later he came back out with another bottle of beer. He took a swig, then accidentally dropped it on the ground where it shattered. He stared at the broken bottle for a moment, then turned and **headed back inside again**.

Is "headed back inside again" correct in the context?

Comment: Sure. I assume from your question that you felt like it was not correct. If you can explain why, maybe we can help in a more meaningful way.

Comment: You might prefer not to use the same phrase as you used only two sentences before.

Comment: **...and headed back to the direction he came from.** or **...and headed back where he came from.** While this might became a little verbose, you might consider using them, in-case you want to avoid repeating your phrase. But there is nothing wrong in your phrase, or in whole, the sentence.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh One heads back **in** a direction, rather than **to** a direction.

Comment: @Ronald Sole That's interesting, does it have anything to do with "direction"? I mean is it wrong to say "I am heading to the office"?

Comment: @Cardinal Not at all. One can head anywhere or to any point. But one heads IN the direction of the office.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you so much. I will take care of that henceforth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's **grammatically** correct but, as Kate Bunting said, it might be better not to repeat the formula "headed back inside." You could change the first one to "went back inside" and make the next one "headed back in."

[You could cut the second "bottle of beer" and end the sentence "came back out with another." You could say "emerged" instead of "came back out". "It slipped from his fingers" is livelier than "accidentally dropped it on the ground." "Stared at the broken glass" would avoid saying "'bottle" again. But there's nothing **grammatically** wrong with what you had.]

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid such annotative writing because it can become repetitive very quickly and, instead, opt for something more implicit. We don't need to describe him reentering the house every time he does if we do it implicitly—we can assume he went back in if we later mention he got another beer. For instance, here I only mention him returning inside the home once without losing any detail of the story.

> He stumbled out onto the porch with his beer, intent on drinking it
> outside. He did the same with his next bottle, only this time it
> slipped from his hand and shattered on the porch floor. He stared at
> it for a moment and then stumbled back in for another drink.